# Adding generated entity classes to the persistence context at runtime

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I have a scenario where i have to create my hibernate entity classes at runtime and persisting these entities without restarting/redeploying my application. I could generate entity sources(.java) and compile them into byte code(.class) using [Java-Poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) and [Open-HFT](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler) libraries at runtime.

But i couldnt add generated entities to the persistence unit at runtime. When i try to persist it im getting Unknown entity error. However i can get and set values of it at runtime..Below code is working for entities that are created manually and exists before application starts. But not working for those generated at runtime.

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("com.mrg.domain.User");
Object model = clazz.newInstance();
model.setName("Name");
model.setSurname("Surname");
entityManager.persist(model); // getting error here..

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.mrg.domain.User
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1184) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
```

I know there are tools for generating entity source files like [eclipse-link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) and [hibernate reverse engineering tools](http://hibernate.org/tools/) but as i see they are not providing a runtime solution for this. Could you suggest me a way for adding generated entities to the persistence context at runtime?

Comment: You could try using this: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic. I'm not sure it fits your use case, though

Comment: I will be looking at it. Thanks